# Split array into two ul columns

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, foreach

I am grabbing a list of occupations for an API and putting them into an array of titles like this:

```
$titles = array();
$arr = $doc->getElementsByTagName("h4");
foreach($arr as $item) {
 $titles[] = $item->nodeValue;
}

$content = occupations_html($titles);

return $content;
```

I then spit those titles out into an unordered list/list items like this:

```
function occupations_html($titles){
  $content = '<ul><li>';
  $content .= implode('</li><li>', $titles);
  $content .= '</li></ul>';

  return $content;
}
```

This works great for creating one unordered list, but I am having trouble spitting this dynamic list out into two even ul's.

Comment: it's an array, you could just [chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk) and do your `<ul>implode</ul>` separately on each chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Try this you can do the ul splitting your self:

```
$i=0;
foreach($array as $value) {
if ($i++ % 3 == 0) {
    $column1[] = $value;
}
if ($i++ % 3 == 1) { // check mod==1
    $column2[] = $value;
}
if ($i++ % 3 == 2) { // check mod==2
    $column3[] = $value;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why some post answers and possible duplicates under the question. If that gets closed (as a duplicate), this would constitute as a "monopoly" answer and leaving no room for others to post another method. Edit: You removed it, *grazie* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like so

```
function array_column_chunk($data, $columns = 2, $preserve_keys = false){
    return array_chunk($data, ceil(count($data) / $columns), $preserve_keys);
}
```

Which will chunk your array into the number of columns you would like instead of the length of the chunks you want.